# php convert string with comma to query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Can I in php convert this

```
$myvar = 'string1,string2,string3'
```

into this to query MySQL:

```
SELECT * ... AND `table`.`colums` IN ('string1' , 'string2' , 'string3') ..
```

Comment: Maybe use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for this

Comment: I see on your profile that you're a freelancer so I hope this doesn't apply to you... but make sure you [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) those queries

Comment: Why were all the answer mass downvoted lol? They all looked like potential solutions??

Comment: @IsThisJavascript One is limited in its scope/usage, one is just flat out wrong, the one that was deleted didn't seem to understand the question

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use split function e.g.

```
list($string1, $string2, $string3) =
    split(",", $my_var);
```

Or you can use explode if using PHP 7

```
$result = explode(",",$my_var);
```

Comment: Split was removed in PHP7.  This also always assumes there are 3 strings, which may not be the case.

Comment: In that case explode  be used explode(",",$my_var) returning an array